# EDMX generates Nullable bool instead of bool

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have written a simple stored procedure that returns one select.

When I have updated my `EDMX model` and added the new stored procedure I wondered to see that the Result that was returned had a Nullable bool (in the stored procedure I always return 0 or 1).

Why does it generates Nullable bool and not bool? And how can I change the stored procedure so that it will generate bool?

Here is the stored procedure (this is not the real stored procedure, its just to demonstrate the problem):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestBool]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT  Title,
            CONVERT(BIT, IIF([Address] = 'America', 1, 0)) IsAmerica,
            CONVERT(BIT, IIF(Duration > 100, 1, 0)) IsLong
    FROM    dbo.Events
    WHERE   UserId > 10
END
```

`Address` is not null while `Duration` is null (but this does not matter because both of the values are generated to Nullable bool).

Here is an image of the `EDMX` result.

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try adding an IsNull function around your Convert with a fallback value. IsNull(Convert..., false)

Comment: @kidshaw Thanks. You are right, if I add ISNULL, it works. But why? I wrote a value that IS NOT NULL... So it shouldn't have ISNULL...

Comment: I think, you need to explicitly say that, you are returning not null values. I am pretty sure that, if you use a outer query and add a where condition like `where IsAmerica is not null` that as well will work.

Comment: @Rahul No, I have just tried and if I add it to where clause, it still does nullable bool.

Comment: Strange! not sure about EF but you can try the alternative as in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a fix to your issue rather an alternative. What if you use a table variable and return that instead like

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestBool]
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @tab table (
Title varchar(100) not null,
IsAmerica bit not null,
IsLong bit not null
);

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO @tab(Title,IsAmerica,IsLong)
    SELECT  Title,
            CONVERT(BIT, IIF([Address] = 'America', 1, 0)) IsAmerica,
            CONVERT(BIT, IIF(Duration > 100, 1, 0)) IsLong
    FROM    dbo.Events
    WHERE   UserId > 10


    SELECT Title,
           IsAmerica,
           IsLong 
           FROM @tab;
END
```

Comment: Yes, as you said, it's not my issue but a solution to solve it. Thanks, but my problem is not the alternative solution, I have many solutions :). Just wanted to understand why...

Comment: Take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034705/generating-entity-framework-based-on-views-nullable-types

Answer (score 2):

The use of `Convert` or `Cast` alone does not guarantee an non-nullable output on the edmx. You need to wrap the whole thing with isnull() as shown below:

```
isnull(cast(case when myBooleanField is not null then 1 else 0 end as bit),0) as IsBooleanValue
```